# Linking multiple third-party accounts for a mobile app?

Tags: registration, hyperlinks, workflow, signup-signon, authentication

My user wants to access personal content from her Spotify, Soundcloud and other third-party accounts through one native mobile application. Imagine a music player for any personal library.

The challenge I face is having our user link all of her accounts. Some may be linked using a Facebook login while others may not. What might a simple authentication process flow like? What's the best interface for 'linking' multiple accounts, especially if they all are accessed through different email/password combinations?

Keep in mind this flow would be for both a native Android and iOS application.

[image: iOS screenshot]

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Dan. Can you show us what you considering so far? What are the main constraints you're encountering?

Comment: @Graham, I just added a photo. When a user taps 'Connect' it would take them to the respective login screen to fill out username/password credentials and then slide back. Is there an easier/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a web-application that requires the same thing.  I present the multiple social-networks in a list of buttons.  First two buttons are to select one (of two) primary social networks:

```
[ Use Facebook ]
[ Use Twitter ]
```

Once the user has connected one of these two primary (or both) I then present the rest of the networks to connect to

```
[ Use Tumblr ]
[ Use Pinterest ]
[ Use SoundCloud ]
```

I'm requiring my users to pick one of the "big two" and the prompting them for the ones I want.

Once their account is created in my system, through a primary interface then I can merge their second-level accounts into their internal profile in my app.  Each site I've integrated with has required some oAuth2 integrations.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Sign-on**

> From the good old days of integrating multiple chat clients (gtalk,
>   aim, yahoo, msn) into a single system (like Meebo!!), this Design-Technical challenge has always been around.

As highlighted in the solution suggested by @edoceo above, oAuth2 requirements are a standard.

**On the design aspects**, Once the user progressively registers with individual services in your app over time, ensure to maintain this state across platforms and devices. This will give a seamless feel and takes off the hassle of re-registering when migrating or reinstalling.

*The image reference below is one of the first single sign-on solution that I had always admired during the good old Nokia days. The apps have changed, the way we communicate changed, but the design challenge is always around.*

[image: Good old chat aggregation]